# How can I create a hero section with an offset image in Chakra UI, similar to the hero section in Tailwind UI?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css, chakra-ui

I am working on a Next.js app with Chakra UI. I want to create a hero section similar to the one in Tailwind UI. I have tried, but it does not look like the one in Tailwind. I am unsure about what the issue might be.

**[Tailwind's Hero With offset image](https://tailwindui.com/components/marketing/sections/heroes#component-1e0bb85307a6f85f730eb5cf8a813837)**

**[CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-https-mrjydg?file=/App.tsx)**